# How to use Auth0's custom database to add a user to a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database-connection, auth0

I am using Auth0 for a login service but I have a need to add a user to a database in MySQL every time an account is registered through Auth0.

They give this following script template but I am a newbie and need help debugging and understanding it.  My specific questions are detailed as comments:

```
function create(user, callback) {

  var connection = mysql({
    host: 'localhost', //what should this be?
    user: 'KNOWN/Understood',
    password: 'KNOWN/Understood',
    database: 'KNOWN/Understood'
  });

  connection.connect();

  var query = "INSERT INTO users SET ?"; //what does this do?

  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function (err, hash) { //what does this do?
    if (err) { return callback(err); }
    var insert = {
      password: hash,
      email: user.email
    };
    connection.query(query, insert, function (err, results) {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      if (results.length === 0) return callback();
      callback(null);
    });
  });
}
```

**Is there anything else I need to change for this script**  or understand or call in for it to work?

I often get the error `missing username for Database connection with requires_username enabled` and I'm unsure what this means.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you already went through [this tutorial on custom databases](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/mysql) so let's address your specific questions.

> `host: 'localhost'` **// What should this be?**

This and the other properties of this object define the way to connect to your custom MySQL database. The database needs to be reached from within Auth0 servers so this needs to be a host name accessible from the Internet.

> `"INSERT INTO users SET ?";` **// What does this do?**

This defines an SQL insert command that uses `?` as a placeholder for later substitution.

If you see where this query is later used, you will noticed it's invoked with an additional `insert` object parameter that will cause the above query to be expanded into something like:

```
INSERT INTO users SET email = 'user@example.com', password = 'asdf34ASws'
```

> `bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function (err, hash)` **// What does this do?**

This hashes the user provided password so that it's not stored in plain text in the database.

---

If you chose to require a `username` in addition to email you need to address this in your custom scripts as I believe the default templates assume that only email will be used.

This means that when creating the user in your database you also need to store the `username` and in the script to verify a user you also need to return the `username`.